# Painting in graphicsview

Tags: c++, qt

I am using the graphics view to paint the graphicsitem in it. Earlier when I clicked the button the respective item was painted only once, to again paint the same entity I had topush the button again. To overcome this I constructed the signal to allow to add the entities multiple times without having the need to push the button again. But when I using vector to store the points.It does not append, limiting its capacity to 2 only. Following is my output and the code
circle.cpp

```
void circle::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button()==Qt::LeftButton) {
        if(mFirstClick){
            x1 = e->pos().x();
            y1 = e->pos().y();
            mFirstClick = false;
            mSecondClick = true;
        }

        else if(!mFirstClick && mSecondClick){
            x2 = e->pos().x();
            y2 = e->pos().y();
            mPaintFlag = true;
            mSecondClick = false;
            update();
            emit DrawFinished();
 _store.set_point(e->pos());
        store_point.push_back(_store);
        qDebug() << _store.getValue();
        qDebug() << "Size of vector =" << store_point.size() << "and" << store_point.capacity();
        update();

        }
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::drawCircle(){
    item2 = new circle;
    scene->addItem(item2);
    qDebug() << "Circle Created";
    connect(item2, SIGNAL(DrawFinished()), this, SLOT(drawCircle()));
}
```

output

```
Circle Created
QPointF(60, 87)
Size of vector = 1 and 1
Circle Created
QPointF(77, 221)
Size of vector = 2 and 2
QPointF(333, 57)
Size of vector = 1 and 1
```

When I remove the signal DrawFinished(), the points store perfectly but the item gets painted only once. I need to pushthe button again:(. Following is the output after removing the signal.

```
QPointF(74, 80)
Size of vector = 1 and 1
QPointF(118, 165)
Size of vector = 2 and 2
QPointF(335, 97)
Size of vector = 3 and 4
```

What needs to be done to perfectly store the points as well as allow repainting. Please do help me to sort out all this.

Comment: Hi ! I don't understand why you are writing some boolean `mFirstClick` and `mSecondClick` in your code, and writing this " to add the entities multiple times without having the need to push the button again" in your header. What do you really want ? Click once, add several shapes, click again to stop ?

Comment: I want when I the push the circle button then I can track the points for drawing the circle multiple no of times. Generally when I push the button circle is tracked single time. I can paint it only once. When I had to draw the circle again I had to click that button again. To overcome this I used DrawFinished. I want to have the same but using this approach I am unable to cope with storage using vectors.

Comment: Ok, as you asked need of Firstclickand all giving it a thought once I found that yes I don't really need it. I used it thinking when user click on first point and second point then it should paint. I removed it, and if I don't use DrawFinished storage is perfect. It gets updated but previously drawn circle vanishes.Using drawFinished provides same problem as earlier.

Comment: What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if this would answer your request but a comment is too small to write what i want to tell you.

I don't really get what is the purpose of your signal `DrawFinished()`. Even if it's obvious thanks to the name, I don't think you need it.

If I sum up what you really want, you have a `QGraphicView` where you want to draw some shapes. Next to it, you have at least one (let's say 3) buttons to select which shapes you want to draw (Circle, Triangle, Rectangle).

Lets say you want to draw some circles, you click on the CircleButton, and then, click on the QGraphicView.

To my mind, I would create something like this:

Two classes, `MainWindow` and `View`, view which inherits from `QGraphicView`. Your three buttons are defined with Qt designer in your MainWindow class. So When you click on a button, you can emit a signal to notify the `View`.

In the `View` class you could have one vector for each shapes.

**MainWindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void drawCircle();
    void drawRectangle();
    void drawTriangle();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    View view;

private slots:
    void slotOnCircleButton();
    void slotOnRectangleButton();
    void slotOnTriangleButton();
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
[...]
void MainWindow::slotOnCircleButton()
{
    emit(drawCircle());
}
[...]
```

**View.h**

```
class View : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit View(QWidget *parent = 0);

    enum DrawingMode
    {
        UNDEFINED,
        CIRCLE,
        TRIANGLE,
        RECTANGLE
    }

signals:

public slots:
    void slotOnDrawCircle();
    void slotOnDrawRectangle();
    void slotOnDrawTriangle();

private:
    DrawingMode mode;
    QVector<QPointF> vectorCircle;
    QVector<QPointF> vectorTriangle;
    QVector<QPointF> vectorRectangle;
};
```

**View.cpp**

```
[...]
void View::slotOnDrawCircle()
{
    this->mode = CIRCLE;
}
[...]

void View::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button()==Qt::LeftButton && this->mode != UNDEFINED)
    {
        qreal x1 = e->pos().x();
        qreal y1 = e->pos().y();

        if(this->mode == CIRCLE)
        {
            this->vectorCircle.append(e->pos());
        }
        else if(...)
        [...]

        // updatePainting();
    }
}
```

When updating the view, you just have to travel throw your 3 vectors and drawing circle, rectangle or triangle.

This way you don't have such a spaghetti code, it's quite clear.

I didn't run the code so there is probable some minor mistakes, don't forget to make your connections and your initializations.